# Make HorizontalPager central item on top of other elements

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How to make `HorizontalPager` center item on top of right items?
(Blue is the "focused"/centered item from the viewpager)

I've tried playing with zIndex but without succeed

```
.zIndex(if(page == currentPage) 1f else 0f)
```

[image: 3 items in the ComposeViewPager]
[image: 2 items in the ComposeViewPager]

Additional code:

```kotlin
@Suppress("CorrectDpValuesDetector")
@Composable
private fun SquaresCodesPager(state: SquaresGroupState, onSelectedListener: (Int) -> Unit, onClickedListener: (Int) -> Unit) {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = 0)
    LaunchedEffect(pagerState) {
        snapshotFlow { pagerState.currentPage }.collect { page ->
            onSelectedListener(page)
        }
    }
    HorizontalPager(
        itemSpacing = -Grid.DP_40,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = (LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp - QR_SIZE) / 2),
        count = state.items.size,
        state = pagerState
    ) { page ->
        Square(pagerState.currentPage, page, state.items[page].square, onClickedListener)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun PagerScope.Square(currentPage: Int, page: Int, bitmap: Bitmap, onClickListener: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier
            .graphicsLayer(animation(page))
            .zIndex(if (page == currentPage) 1f else 0f)
            .background(Background.BgSecondary)
            .size(SQUARE_SIZE),
        bitmap = ...
        contentDescription = ...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now fixed in the release 1.5.0-alpha04.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.5.0-alpha04